# Как реализовать обновление шаблона?

Tags: javascript, шаблоны, шаблонизаторы

Допустим, есть такой шаблон

```
<script id="test" type="text/html">
    Test: {message}
    <div class="body">
        {data}
    </div>
</script>
```

Вот его живой грубый пример https://jsfiddle.net/0ykLrsx9/

Как можно сделать обновление `message` или `data`? Если с `data` ещё более-менее понятно, просто обновляем содержимое `.body`, то с `message` не все так однозначно.

Можно сохранять в памяти шаблон и перезаписывать его, но тогда будут умирать все события, которые навешаны на элементы

Comment: Вам нужно связывание как в ангуляре, например? Там чуть сложнее шаблоны билдятся.

Comment: Знаком только с vue, но да, скорей всего. Исходник читать пытался, но это немного ад. Может есть статья посвященная этому? Не как отслеживать изменение переменной, а именно как крафтить и обновлять шаблоны